# How to convert bool type to const char*

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to use a member function of `PubSubClient` library that takes one of the parameters `const char*`, but I need to pass a `bool type` variable from my code to that member function (as a payload). How can I achieve that?

The member function of the library as follows:

```
boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char* topic, const char* payload) {
    return publish(topic,(const uint8_t*)payload,strlen(payload),false);
}
```

Comment: How about `publish(topic, type?"T":"F");` ?  (the code receiving the value would have to know about the T=true F=false convention of course)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I compiled the program without any error. However, I need to upload the code to esp32 to make sure everything works fine.